# How to replace word in url using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to replace a word from url. i try many code but. not working

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/resetter/(.*)$ $1/reseter-de-puces/$2 [L]
```

i want to redirect

```
catalogue-encros/resetter/epson/resetter-pour-epson-ancienne-génération/8345-37457
```

to

```
catalogue-encros/reseter-de-puces/epson/resetter-pour-epson-ancienne-génération/8345-37457
```

i have added www redirect which is work fine

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you try with `.*` rather than just `.`?

Comment: yes RewriteRule ^(.*)/resetter/(.*)$ $1/reseter-de-puces/$2 [L]
but it's not work

Comment: "not working" is not a constructive error description. What happens? Do you get an error? Does the universe implode?

Comment: it's redirect to 404, as it redirect without any redirect code

Comment: What URL do you test with? Please specify all relevant information. Don't rely on people dragging things out of you. Make things easy for those willing to help you.

Comment: Is that `.htaccess` file considered at all by the server? Try putting a definite syntax error in there. It might be you have not enabled use of such files.

Comment: i have added other redirect and it's work fine. please check updated question

Comment: Is `/catalogue-encros/` a real directory?

Comment: Maybe one of your other rewrite rules has a `[L]` after it... meaning "this is the last rule"? Also - if you enable logging on your server, the log will tell you exactly what it did when it encountered this rule. But typically a 404 means "file not found". Suggesting that either the redirect is not happening, or it is wrong. Put something in the "unredirected" directory - see if that page is served up (i.e. redirect is not happening at all). See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for hints on how to enable higher level logging (slow: use for debug, then disable!)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `/` before the `$1`, try:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/resetter/(.*)$ /$1/reseter-de-puces/$2 [L]
```

Without the `/` before `$1` your would url would have turned into something like:

```
http://domain.com/www/var/home/domain.com/somedirectory/reseter-de-puces/
```

Comment: That actually depends... He is using a `.htaccess` style file. So the `/` might be wrong.

Comment: If you change the `[L]` to `[R]` and try it again, what shows in the url?

Comment: added [R]. but not success. no change in URL

Comment: So you type in something like `http://domain.com/catalogue-encros/resetter/epson/resetter-pour-epson-ancienne-génération/8345-37457` as the url and nothing happens?

Comment: exactly. no change in URL

Comment: Did you try remove the other rewrite rules (doubtful it would matter). Or try it in a different browser?